# Progress Developer Studio 11.6 Not Responding

Tags: eclipse, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a form that requires many controls. Unfortunately when I double-click on the events for controls (ex : Keydown, etc) IDE becomes not responding.

How to fix this issue?

Log file Link : [Log File](https://mega.nz/#!f8Qj0C6Y!vOPlrRdUPXQO4Z_FyeqBXNvFfMaRab8TiZ9tc48_B-4)

[image: Not Responding]

Comment: `com.progress.ipccom.IPCException: Attempting to send callback on an server instance that is not running` happens in the UI thread (in SWT there is only a single UI thread) causing the UI to freeze. Please report this bug to Progress OpenEdge.

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: It's 32 bit Mike

Comment: My recommendation would be to try out 64 bit PDSOE (OpenEdge Classroom edition) and the most recent service pack/hotfix. 11.6.4 or 11.7.3.007